# Two problems, using charAt for undefined input and looping output

Tags: java, output, charat

So, I posted this nearly identical code yesterday, asking about how to leave the punctuation at the end of a reversed sentence after using `.split`. I'm still struggling with it, but I'm also having another issue with the same code: And here is my screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/peiEA.png

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer; // for splitting


public class MyTokenTester
{
    public static void main(String\[\] args)
    {
        Scanner enter = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sentinel = ""; // condition for do...while
        String backward = ""; // empty string 
        char lastChar = '\0';




        do
        {

        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence: ");
        String sentence = enter.nextLine();
        String\[\] words = sentence.split(" "); // array words gets tokens
    //  System.out.printf("The string is%s",sentence.substring(sentence.length()));


        for (int count = words.length -1; count>=0; count--) // reverse the order and assign backward each token
        {
            backward += words\[count\] + " ";


        }


        System.out.println(backward); // print original sentence in reverse order

        System.out.println("Hit any key to continue or type 'quit' to stop now: ");
            sentinel = enter.nextLine();
                sentinel = sentinel.toLowerCase(); // regardless of case






        } while (!sentinel.equals("quit")); // while the sentinel value does not equal quit, continue loop

        System.out.println("Programmed by ----");



    } // end main



} // end class MyTokenTester][1]][1]
```

As you guys can probably see my from screen shot, when the user is prompted to add another sentence in, the previous sentence is read back again.

My questions are:

1. How do  I use `charAt` to identify a character at an undefined index (user input with varying lengths)
2. How do I stop my sentence from reading back after the user decides to continue.

Again, as I said, I'd posted this code yesterday, but the thread died and I had additional issues which weren't mentioned in the original post.

Comment: I tried to add a screen shot to my output. Here is the link.   [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/peiEA.png

Comment: What if you do `String sentence = null;` and `String[ ] words = null;` at the end of every loop so it can be garbage collected?

Comment: Can you clarify on what you mean in part 1? Specifically what do you mean by an "undefined index"

Comment: Part of what I'm trying to do is reverse a sentence: Hello my name is Bob! should become Bob is my name Hello! So, the whole sentence is reversed, but the punctuation is kept at the end.                                    It's been suggested to me that I use charAt() to find the last character in the sentence and use that to then place it at the end. I don't know how to use charAt() for a String in which I dont know where the last index is, as it is the user who determines the length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address part 2, if you want to stop the sentence from reading back previous input, then reset `backward` to an empty string, because as it stands now, you're constantly adding new words to the variable. So to fix this, add this line of code right before the end of your `do-while` loop,

```
backward = "";
```

To address part 1, if you want to check the last character in a string, then first you have to know what is the last index of this string. Well, a string has indexes from `0` to `str.length()-1`. So if you want to access the very last character in the user input, simply access the last word in your `words` array (indexed from `0` to `words.length - 1`) by doing the following,

```
words[count].charAt(words[count].length() - 1);
```

Note that `count` is simply `words.length - 1` so this can be changed to your liking.

Comment: Thank you, this answered part 2 of my question. I've been having this same issue before, where I do not reset things after loops. Much appreciated.

Comment: @srmjr Check my edit for part 1. Also glad I could help. If you found the answer helpful then don't forget to mark it as accepted. Good luck coding!

Comment: So, I added this: lastChar = words[count].charAt(words[count].length() - 1); for debugging purposes, within the loop, to use with System.out.println(), outside of the loop                                                            However, it is giving me the last letter of the first word ( I believe ) when I type Hello my name is Bob!, it gives me 'o' rather than the exclamation

Comment: @srmjr It's because your putting that line after the loop is done, so by that time `count` will be 0. To fix this, replace `count` with `words.length() - 1` so change it to `words[words.length - 1].charAt(words[words.length - 1.length() - 1);`

Answer (score 1):

1) So you have this array of strings `words`. Before adding each word to the `backward` string, you can use something like: `words[count].chartAt(words[count].length() - 1)`. It will return you the charater at the last position of this word. Now you are able to do you checking to know wether it is a letter or any special char.

2) The problem is not that it is reading the previous line again, the problem is that the `backward` string still has the previous result. As you are using a `+` operator to set the values of the string, it will keep adding it together with the previous result. You should clean it before processing the other input to have the result that you want.

Comment: @srmjr just added the part 1

Comment: Am I able to set two answers to correct? I have two of you, both helping me out greatly. So this line of code appears to be giving the last character of the first WORD in the sentence, I guess because they've been tokenized? I'm trying to find the last character in the total String.

Comment: @srmjr You cannot, but that's no problem. I thought you wanted to check it for every word (maybe there is a comma in the middle of the sentence or something like that). So if you want to check just the end of the input string, you can use `sentence.chartAt(sentence.length() - 1)`. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

here is your code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class main{

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner enter = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sentinel = ""; // condition for do...while
    String backward = ""; // empty string 
    char lastChar = '\0';

    do
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence: ");
        String sentence = enter.nextLine();
        String[] words = sentence.split(" "); // array words gets tokens
        //  System.out.printf("The string is%s",sentence.substring(sentence.length()));
        List<String> items = Arrays.asList(words);
        Collections.reverse(items);

        System.out.println(generateBackWardResult(items)); // print original sentence in reverse order
        System.out.println("Hit any key to continue or type 'quit' to stop now: ");
        sentinel = enter.nextLine();
        // i use quals ignore case, makes the code more readable
    } while (!sentinel.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")); // while the sentinel value does not equal quit, continue loop

    System.out.println("Programmed by ----");
} // end main

static String generateBackWardResult(List<String> input){
    String result="";
    for (String word:input){
        result =result +" "+word;
    }
    return result;
 }
} // end class MyTokenTester][1]][1]
```

there are also some thing to mention:
* never invent the wheel again! (for reverting an array there are lots of approaches in java util packages, use them.)
*write clean code, do each functionality, i a separate method. in your case you are doing the reverting and showing the result in a single method.